# Generating Table / array on the fly in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

I need to create postgresql function

```
CREATE FUNCTION date_ranges (_start date, end date) 
  RETURNING TABLE(day_in_range date) AS...
```

if I call date_ranges('2010-06-01', 2010-06-05')
I should receive

```
2010-06-01
2010-06-02
2010-06-03
2010-06-04
2010-06-05
```

Any Ideas how to do it?

Comment: Look at the last example: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-srf.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on Postgresql 8.4:

```
SELECT generate_series(_start ::timestamp,_end ::timestamp,'1 day');
```

Example:

```
postgres=# SELECT generate_series('2010-06-01'::timestamp,
postgres-# '2010-06-05'::timestamp,'1 day')::date;
 generate_series
-----------------
 2010-06-01
 2010-06-02
 2010-06-03
 2010-06-04
 2010-06-05
```

On older versions:

```
SELECT '2010-06-01'::date + step FROM
generate_series(0,'2010-06-05'::date - '2010-06-01'::date,1) AS t(step);
```

Comment: Works perfect - THANK YOU (specially for older version I use 8.1) - bensiu

Comment: 8.1 will be EOL this year, start upgrading to a newer version.